# How to port hashlib from python to c#

Tags: c#, .net, python

I am trying to port the hashlib library from python to C#:

```
shaA = hashlib.sha256()
        shaA.update(yy)     
        shaA.update(xx)
        shaB = shaA.copy()
        hashA = shaA.digest()

        #Hash B
        shaB.update(yy)
        shaA = shaB.copy()
        hashB = shaB.digest()

        #Hash C
        shaA.update(xx)
        hashC = shaA.digest()
```

My problem is that I dont really know what update() means in terms of SHA256() in .NET, and also the copy (which SHA256 in .NET doesnt support) and digest.

If anyone can help me out with that, i'd be more than grateful!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think -- not sure, not tested -- that your example code is roughly equivalent to this:

```
byte[] hashA, hashB, hashC;

using (var sha = new SHA256Managed())
{
    hashA = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(yy + xx));
    hashB = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(yy + xx + yy));
    hashC = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(yy + xx + yy + xx));
}
```

The various Python methods are explained in [the `hashlib` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html).

`copy` makes a clone of the hash object's current state; `update` appends a new string onto the hash object's existing input string; `digest` generates the hash (aka, message digest) from the hash object's existing input string and returns it as a sequence of bytes.

There are no equivalents that I'm aware of in .NET or C#. To be honest, there doesn't seem much value in porting `hashlib`. Using the built-in .NET hash libraries gives you shorter and more understandable code, in my opinion.

Comment: The built in hash libraries lead to very ugly code in my experience. Having an `update` and `digest` method looks much cleaner IMO than the .net equivalent. And working around the lack of copy(if you need that feature) is probably very expensive too.

Comment: @CodeInChaos Haven't you heard of abstractions? It's still much less work than porting a whole library.

Comment: @the_drow I didn't say porting the library is a good idea. But I found it strange that LukeH said: "Using the built-in .NET hash libraries gives you shorter and more understandable code, in my opinion.". Which doesn't match my experience. The .net code that'd correspond to the above python code is *much* uglier. But of course the right way to address the problem are some helper methods, not a full library port from python.

Answer (score 0):

You do know that the .NET framework contains a cryptography library, do you?
Here's the [SHA256](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256.aspx) implementation for .NET.
[This](http://www.devx.com/codemag/Article/16747) is a nice overview of the cryptography library.

If you are having trouble using the .NET cryptography library maybe you should find out if there is some way to implement what you want in C# instead of porting a whole library to do what you want.